# JunOS: Password recovery has failed

Tags: juniper-junos

I am trying to recover a root password on an MX80 but I'm receiving some errors and have no idea what they mean (it's not live so suggestive "disruptive" steps is acceptable);

The steps I have taken are as follows;

- Reboot the router, at the prompt `Hit [Enter] to boot immediately, or space bar for command prompt` - I hit space
- I enter `boot -s` to boot into single user mode
- At the prompt `Enter full pathname of shell or 'recovery' for root password recovery or RETURN for /bin/sh:` I enter `recovery`
- Once into the CLI I enter configuration mode and then attempt to reset root password and commit the config;

This is were I experience the errors; What do they mean, and how can I correct this? Does it even need correcting (I'd assume so!):

```
[edit]
root# set system root-authentication plain-text-password 
New password:
Retype new password:

[edit]
root# commit    
error: could not open database: /var/run/db/juniper.data: No such file or directory
error: Database open failed for file '/var/run/db/juniper.data': No such file or directory
error: commit failed: daemon file propagation failed

[edit]
root# WATCHDOG_TIMER : Loss of soft watchdog
panic: Loss of soft watchdog
Entering boot mastership relinquish phase
KDB: enter: panic
[thread pid 11 tid 100005 ]
Stopped at      kdb_enter+0x1a4:        addis   r3, r0, -0x5f7a
db>
```

The MX80 is running JunOS 11.4R1.14. I have rebooted and the password hasn't been reset. Should I try again, or is something wrong with this router which I should address first? I don't want to damage anything.

**UPDATE**

As an update to this; Today I booted into recovery mode again and did nothing, I was on the phone with the router sitting at the "root>". Whilst on the phone for a few minutes the router suddenly had a panic;

```
Enter full pathname of shell or 'recovery' for root password recovery or RETURN for /bin/sh: recovery

Performing filesystem consistency checks ...
/dev/da0s1a: 1466 files, 91908 used, 361032 free (56 frags, 45122 blocks, 0.0% fragmentation)
/dev/da0s1e: 9 files, 8 used, 50273 free (17 frags, 6282 blocks, 0.0% fragmentation)

Performing mount of main filesystems ...

Performing filesystem consistency of secondary filesystems ...
/dev/da1s1f: 232 files, 362550 used, 1105677 free (125 frags, 138194 blocks, 0.0% fragmentation)

Performing mount of secondary filesystems ...
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Verified jboot signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Verified jbase-ppc-11.4R1.14 signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Mounted jkernel package on /dev/md1...
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
veriexec: fingerprint for dev 73, file 49356 f743694d46ccdfd6bc72f0793c1cc0e8e5bdf80e != b3dfc26ab4c595f569e86791aa3dcfa4a277892c
Verified jkernel-ppc-11.4R1.14 signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Mounted jpfe package on /dev/md2...
Mounted jdocs package on /dev/md3...
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Verified jdocs-11.4R1.14 signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Mounted jroute package on /dev/md4...
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Verified jroute-ppc-11.4R1.14 signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Mounted jcrypto package on /dev/md5...
Verified manifest signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
Verified jcrypto-ppc-11.4R1.14 signed by PackageProduction_11_4_0
machdep.bootsuccess: 1 -> 1

Performing initialization of management services ...
mgd: error: could not open database: /var/run/db/schema.db: No such file or directory
mgd: error: Database open failed for file '/var/run/db/schema.db': No such file or directory
mgd: error: could not open database schema: /var/run/db/schema.db
mgd: error: could not open database schema
mgd: error: database schema is out of date, rebuilding it
mgd: error: could not open database: /var/run/db/juniper.data: No such file or directory
mgd: error: Database open failed for file '/var/run/db/juniper.data': No such file or directory
mgd: error: Cannot read configuration: Could not open configuration database

Performing checkout of management services ...

NOTE: Once in the CLI, you will need to enter configuration mode using
NOTE: the 'configure' command to make any required changes. For example,
NOTE: to reset the root password, type:
NOTE:    configure
NOTE:    set system root-authentication plain-text-password
NOTE:    (enter the new password when asked)
NOTE:    commit
NOTE:    exit
NOTE:    exit
NOTE: When you exit the CLI, you will be asked if you want to reboot
NOTE: the system

Starting CLI ... 
root> WATCHDOG_TIMER : Loss of soft watchdog
panic: Loss of soft watchdog
###Entering boot mastership relinquish phase
KDB: enter: panic
[thread pid 11 tid 100005 ]
Stopped at      kdb_enter+0x1a4:        addis   r3, r0, -0x5f7a
db>
```

I will reinstall and see what happens.

Comment: I have a feeling that there may be a problem with the os which is stopping you from changing the password.  I would try upgrading or downgrading the os to see if that will work.  But of course, always back up your configuration and os before doing so.

Comment: I agree this sounds like the router is booting from the backup image and is not able to write the config back to permanent storage , I too recommend a software update , if this does not resolve then I would look at hardware with TAC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a corrupt filesystem - was the router rebooted w/o proper shutdown? If it is the case, try booting from USB stick and re-install (with re-partition) the CF card:

request system snapshot partition media compact-flash (or similar, check manual for exact device name)

Comment: This is the logical way to proceed, so I took this route. I wipe the router and reinstalled. Working fine now.